# Powershell emulate Linux touch to create multiple files

Tags: powershell

I am new to powershell and I am trying to create a function that can take a list of space separated files and create a new file for each of them in the current directory. Then do an `ls` command to view the directory to confirm the new files have been added. Here is what I have that is not working:

```
function touch{
  params([String[]] $files)
   ForEach($file in $files){
   New-Item $file
  }
ls
}
```

This doesn't seem to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing called `params()`, it's `param()`. I've also added `Out-Null` because `New-Item` returns a `FileInfo`-object for each file it creates. Without it, the new files would show twice: once from `New-Item` and once from `ls`.

```
function touch{
  param([String[]] $files)
   ForEach($file in $files){
   New-Item -Path $file | Out-Null
  }
ls
}

touch -files "test.txt", "test2.txt        

    Directory: C:\Users\frode\TouchFolder

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       30.03.2016     20:56              0 test.txt
-a----       30.03.2016     20:56              0 test2.txt
```

Be aware that you will get on error if the file exists or if you use a path like `test\test3.txt` if the subfolder `test` is missing. You can force overwrite and subfolder-creation using `New-Item -Path $file -Force`.

To use arguments, try:

```
function touch{
    ForEach($file in $args){
        New-Item -Path $file | Out-Null
    }

    Get-ChildItem
}

touch index.html users.html "test 3.txt"

    Directory: C:\Users\frode\TouchFolder


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       30.03.2016     21:19              0 index.html
-a----       30.03.2016     21:19              0 test 3.txt
-a----       30.03.2016     21:19              0 users.html
```

Comment: Should I use `args` instead of `param()`? I am trying to call this without commas, quotes or a "-file." Something like this: `touch index.html users.html`

Comment: Yes, see updated answer. However, I would really recommend using parameters and comma-separated (which is how we define an array in PowerShell) as it is how it's done in PowerShell. You should learn the language and not try to mimic something else

Answer (score -1):

As originally stated, I wanted to emulate the Linux `touch` command so that I could simply type:

`touch file.txt file2.txt`

Here is what I ended up with:

```
function touch(){ 
   foreach($file in $args){
     New-Item -Path $file | Out-Null   
   }
  ls
}
```

The `ls` command is all that was added that goes past the linux `touch` command.

Comment: `ls` is an Alias for `Get-ChildItem` so you're much better off using `Get-ChildItem` in your scripts as seen in Frode's example.